# how to handlde multiple concurrent request in flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I wanted to create a variable which will keep the request object per restful service call during entire slice. I am not sure what is the best way to handle it in Flask. I am using Flask + Mongoengine. The reason for this is because I want to pass the same information to every CRUD operations to record the request.

Will

`g`

is right option or something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to set **`app.run(threaded=True))`** in order to make your `Flask` application capable of handling multiple concurrent requests.

You may also like to go through the URL - http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/deploy/.

Comment: Thanks for answer. what about g instance, will it be shared across threads or have different instance of g?